# Can't reply to third party imported Messages in Microsoft Teams using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

History:
I have created team & imported messages as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams). After import and completing migration when I access the team from Teams web interface I am not able to reply to the messages imported in Migration mode.

On inspection, I found following error showing in Chrome console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
2021-09-03T09:11:13.550Z MessageService: actionHandlerSendMessage: Error while sending message 2644495256888454000 executed by OAM: {"statusCode":404,"headers":{"cache-control":"no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache","content-length":"184","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","contextid":"tcid=0,server=msgapi-production-wjp-azsc5-1-12,cv=2O3RTUcHh0+S7y96owxjMg.0","pragma":"no-cache"},"errorMessage":"{\r\n  \"subCode\": \"PostNotFound\",\r\n  \"details\": \"Post does not exist in the thread.\",\r\n  \"errorCode\": null,\r\n  \"errorSubCode\": null\r\n}","errorCode":404,"request":{},"conversationId":"19:ef2148b145374e49b51879d260a363a5@thread.tacv2"}
```

Please help me understand the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Karpe29, We tried to repro the issue. We are also not able to reply to messages imported in migration mode and got the same console error. We have raised a bug for this and concerned team is looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

We have raised a bug for this. The issue is fixed. Now we can reply to third party imported Messages in Microsoft Teams using Graph API